# Adding forms based on user button clicks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering if there were any strategies to adding forms based on a button a user clicked. For example, lets say I have a form with artist, title, and genre. Then i have a button under those forms that say 'add another song', then it should display another set of fields of artist title, and genre. What are some strategies I can go about achieving this? Is there any ruby specific functions I can use, or am I stuck having to use something like JavaScript? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called nested attributes.

You will also need to use JavaScript as well if you need the number of ( artist, title, and genre ) forms to be dynamic (set by user in the browser using a button).

you can find an example about this type of forms in this [repository](https://github.com/ryanb/complex-form-examples)

Comment: Thank you I will research on this and see what I come up with